# netstandard 2.0 does not have AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

I have just upgraded a `net451` classic dotnet project to multi-target project using `net461/netstandard2.0` with reasonable success.

Did however come across this compiler error for `net461` when it comes to gaining access legacy configuration files via:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`

This appears to not be a thing in `netstandard2.0` :) Anyone know of any work arounds or good solutions?

Comment: Aaargh! Title is meant to be: netstandard 2.0 does NOT have AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile

Comment: Remember you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46226283/edit) the question yourself to fix any mistakes or add additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.hishambinateya.com/goodbye-platform-abstractions), which I found when looking for replacement for `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath`, it should be either of:

- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName`
- `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name`

Just like you, I've just found out that the first one does not exist in recent 2.0 so I'll be using the `GetEntryAssembly` name..

..however keep in mind that `GetEntryAssembly` may be `null` when used i.e. from within a test runner like xUnit, or probably will be wrong if your appcode is ran from another not-yours hosting/startup module, etc - so that is **not a perfect replacement**.

Answer (score 5):

Add the ConfigurationManager as a NuGet

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Use ConfigurationManager in C#

```
var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
Log4NetLogger.Configure(configFile.FilePath);
```